# Is that possible to add icons to the login screen top-panel?

Tags: icons, panel, gnome-panel

Is that possible to add icons(other than defaults) to the login screen top-panel?

[image]

If yes then which applications icons will be added to the login screen top panel other than the defaults(*onboard,sound,network-manager,etc*).And how do i add that?

*I am running Ubuntu 13.10*

Comment: Its the lightdm login manager, so you will have to edit its files `/usr/share` directly. I think there was a lightdm customizer that allowed this and changing background, but I don't if it still works any more..

Comment: can i get this wallpaper?

Comment: @Utkarsh i downloaded the above picture from google image search.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm on 12.04, but this will work on 13.10 also.

Yes, it is possible to change the indicators for the unity-greeter. We could use GSettings to modify the settings, but because the unity-greeter is only run by the lightdm user, (so it's settings doesn't affect anyone else) it is easiest to just write a `.override` file.

### 1. **Check the default indicators**

You can see your default indicators in the `dconf-editor` or int the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml` file. In the latter file you will see a key similar to this:

```
 <key name="indicators" type="as">
  <default>['ug-keyboard', 'ug-accessibility', 'session', 'datetime', 'power', 'soundmenu', 'application']</default>
  <summary>Which indicators to load</summary>
</key>
```

, those are the defaults for me. Check your's first.

On 13.10 this key looks like this:

```
<key name="indicators" type="as">
  <default>['ug-accessibility', 'com.canonical.indicator.keyboard', 'com.canonical.indicator.session', 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime', 'com.canonical.indicator.power', 'com.canonical.indicator.sound', 'application']</default>
  <summary>Which indicators to load</summary>
</key>
```

### 2 . **Check the available indicators**

You can check your available indicators in the `/usr/lib/indicators3/7/` directory, or in the `/usr/share/unity/indicators/` directory.

### 3. **Write an override file**

Just write a file with similar contents and save it as `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/myoverride.gschema.override`

For 12.04

```
[com.canonical.unity-greeter]
indicators=['ug-keyboard', 'ug-accessibility', 'session', 'datetime', 'power', 'soundmenu', 'application', 'messaging']
```

For 13.10

```
[com.canonical.unity-greeter]
indicators=['ug-accessibility', 'com.canonical.indicator.keyboard', 'com.canonical.indicator.session', 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime', 'com.canonical.indicator.power', 'com.canonical.indicator.sound', 'application', 'messages']
```

In the 12.04 version I added the *messaging* indicator to the default list of 12.04. In the 13.10 version I added the *messages* indicator to the default listof 13.10.  I simply added them to the default list shown in **STEP 1**, you can do that too, or remove some from the default indicators if you don't want them to show up on the login screen.  (Watch out for the apostrophes.) **IMPORTANT**: On 12.04 you have to keep the *'ug-keyboard'* and the *'session'* indicator in the list, so **DO NOT** remove them if you have them in the default line, or lightdm will stuck in an endless loop. (like [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/392481/221281) )

**Naming conventions in the override file:** For files in the `/usr/lib/indicators3/7/` directory the filename's preceding "lib" and the ending ".so" are not important, so for a file named libmessaging.so we could use 'libmessaging.so', 'libmessaging' or 'messaging'. For the files in the `/usr/share/unity/indicators/` directory the filename's preceding "com.canonical.indicator." is not important, so for the "com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth" file we could use 'com.canonical.indicator.bluetooth' or simply "bluetooth'.

### 4. Backup (just in case)

Make a backup of the `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/gschemas.compiled` file.

### 5. Compile

After all this run

```
sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas
```

### 6. Check the results

After this try to logout and see if it worked. Or you can also do a test of the login-screen without logging out, if you try from a terminal:

```
lightdm --test-mode
```

or

```
unity-greeter --test-mode
```

For me on 12.04 the messaging indicator worked, my printersmenu indicator doesn't. On 13.10 I tested with the messages indicator and it didn't show up, but neither produced erros, so I guessed that it is by design not showing up on the greeter-screen, because it is mostly useless there. So I checked the `/usr/share/unity/indicators/com.canonical.indicator.messages` file and it confirmed that it doesn't have a [desktop_greeter] section like e.g the session indicator has. So If you wan't the messages indicator (or another indicator without the [desktop_greeter] section) to show up on the login screen (even if it is mostly useless there), you will also have to edit its file in the `/usr/share/unity/indicators/` directory, and make a copy of the [desktop] section in that file and rename the copy to [desktop_greeter] section. E.g for the messages indicator I ended up with this file for `/usr/share/unity/indicators/com.canonical.indicator.messages`:

```
[Indicator Service]
Name=indicator-messages
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/messages
Position=50

[desktop]
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/messages/desktop

[phone]
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/messages/phone

[desktop_greeter]
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/messages/desktop
```

After doing this change in the file, the messages indicator did show up on the login screen for 13.10 also.

**If something goes bad** and the login screen doesn't come up, just switch to a virtual console <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and restore your backup `gschemas.compiled` file. Or remove your `myoverride.gschema.override` file and run `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas` again. If the lighdtm stucks in an endless loop, and you can't switch to virtual console, just press the <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> magic key combo, this will kill lightdm and after this you can switch to the virtual console and do the repair.

*Which indicators can you use?* I don't know, I have only the defaults, but I guess you can try out any which installs itself to those directories listed above. (Or you could [write an own indicator](http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/technologies/application-indicators/) as always.)

*Source for all of these?* I looked into the code: [link](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-greeter-team/unity-greeter/trunk/view/head:/src/menubar.vala) and [link](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~unity-greeter-team/unity-greeter/trunk/view/head:/data/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml)

Comment: did you want to say is find the `libmessaging.so` file then copy an paste it in the `/usr/lib/indicators3/7` directory,am i correct?

Comment: @AvinashRaj No, I meant that it is possible that the directory where the unity-greeter looks for the indicators is different by versions. From the source code I could only get, that there are 2 directories where the unity-greeter searches for indicators. The `/usr/share/unity/indicators` looks same per versions, but the `/usr/lib/indicators3/7` director can be different by version. So I meant to search for the installed default indicators, look where they are stored, and simply look in that directory to see what indicators are available, then you can use their names in the list.

Comment: see http://i.imgur.com/JPrincG.png

Comment: @AvinashRaj You can try out all the indicators from those 2 directories. If you use one from `usr/lib/...` directory, then the naming conventions what I wrote above holds, so `syncindicator` is enough but you can use `libsyncindicator.so` also. For the other directory you can also use the whole name of the file, or you can leave out the `com.canonical.indicator.` section. So in your case a valid line in the override file would be something like this: `indicators=['libsyncindicator.so', 'printersmenu', 'libapplication', 'com.canonical.indicator.sound', 'messages']`

Comment: i don't want to fall into any critical situation plz try it on ubuntu 13.10 and notify me if it works.

Comment: @AvinashRaj I checked the solution for 13.10 and updated the answer on how to make some indicators to show up, although they are designed to hide themselves on the login-screen. This was the problem why the messages indicator didn't show up for you in 13.10. Hope now your problem is solved.