# Edit the Unity-Greeter theme

Tags: lightdm, unity-greeter

I am trying to get rid of some of the indicator icons on the Lightdm login screen (or maybe just get rid of everything). No luck so far.

The file I am editing is @ /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml  on Ubuntu  12.04.3.

After making the changes, I compile with `sudo glib-compile-schemas /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/` command.

When I test with `lightdm --test-mode` it seems that Lightdm is going on an endless loop.

Anybody here has successfully removed the indicators before?  I just want the power indicator, or perhaps if it's possible, totally remove all indicators.

Thanks!

Edit: By *power* I meant the shutdown/restart indicator, which is rightfully called session indicator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested it now on 12.04. If I remove every indicator I get the same problem what you get, stuck in an endless loop.

I tested some variations and it looks like you can't remove the **ug-keyboard** and of course the **session** indicator. All the other I can remove without problem.  So just keep those 2. Then you will have only the keyboard and the power on the login screen.

To get out-of the endless loop press <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>PrtSc</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, this will terminate lightdm (and all processes) after this you can switch to the virtual console <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> and repair what you need to.

Comment: I just want to add that on 13.10, removing **com.canonical.indicator.keyboard** works perfectly. I removed that and **ug-accessibility**, since I don't see a point in having them.