# How can I add a custom python indicator to the unity-greeter login screen?

Tags: unity, python, login, indicator, lightdm

I've installed a custom indicator called [PRIME Indicator](https://github.com/beidl/prime-indicator) and it shows up in the top panel (next to date time etc) **after** I login.

I would like to show the indicator **before** login on the unity-greeter lightdm login screen, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have attempted to use the information provided in the following answer:

[Is that possible to add icons to the login screen top-panel?](https://askubuntu.com/a/392293)

but *PRIME Indicator* is not installed in either `/usr/lib/indicators3/7/` or `/usr/share/unity/indicators/`, so I don't know what to do.

I can create an override file like this:

```
$ /usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/myoverride.gschema.override
[com.canonical.unity-greeter]
indicators=['com.canonical.indicator.keyboard', 'com.canonical.indicator.datetime', 'com.canonical.indicator.power', 'com.canonical.indicator.sound', 'application', 'prime']
```

**NOTE**: I added a `prime` entry.

Also, I created a file here:

```
$ /usr/share/unity/indicators/prime
[Indicator Service]
Name=indicator-prime
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/prime
Position=50

[desktop]
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/prime/desktop

[phone]
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/prime/phone

[desktop_greeter]
ObjectPath=/com/canonical/indicator/prime/desktop
```

However, this doesn't work because I don't know what the correct `ObjectPath` should be.

Q1: Is it possible to make PRIME-indicator show **before** login?

Q2: How do I do it?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make indicator-sysmonitor as a default indicator on the login screen](http://askubuntu.com/questions/628720/how-to-make-indicator-sysmonitor-as-a-default-indicator-on-the-login-screen)